# Specific SQL query to count

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm developing a CRM, that's why I created poles to separate my users.

I created a view which gathered all the information of a user.

I'm looking to know how to count the number of users logged in by pole.

In my VIEW I have a `user_online` field.

I also have a `pole_name` field.

I tried this request but it doesn't work.

```
SELECT pole_name, COUNT(user_online) AS nbr_online FROM `ViewProjet_userPoleRole` GROUP BY pole_name
```

Which gives me the total number of users of a pole and therefore not if it is online.

[image: data]

And finally, here is my entire VIEW.

[image: VIEW]

I have tried several requests, but I cannot.

Comment: Maybe you can share the basic definition of both of your tables. Also whats the outcome of your query?

Comment: I just edited my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use **conditional aggregation** as following:

> ```
> SELECT
>     POLE_NAME,
>     SUM(CASE WHEN USER_ONLINE = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS NBR_ONLINE
> FROM VIEWPROJET_USERPOLEROLE
> GROUP BY POLE_NAME
> ```

or If you want to know only Poles with minimum one online user then put the condition in the `WHERE` clause as follows:

> ```
> SELECT
>     POLE_NAME,
>     COUNT(1) AS NBR_ONLINE
> FROM VIEWPROJET_USERPOLEROLE
> WHERE USER_ONLINE = 'Y'
> GROUP BY POLE_NAME
> ```

If you represent online user by some other kind of norms then use them in `WHEN` clause of the `CASE` statement accordingly.

Cheers!!

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your request sends me back the poles but not the number of users online. 
I have the impression that it is reversed, that it rather shows me the number of offline users.

Comment: Disagree!!! It is counting the number of records where `USER_ONLINE = 'Y'`

Comment: What does "Y" mean? I think we are on the right track with your request.

Comment: read this from my answer: **If you represent online user by some other kind of norms then use them in WHEN clause of the CASE statement accordingly.**

Comment: I had not seen, thank you for clarifying me, I will remember this lesson !

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT pole_name, COUNT(user_id) AS nbr_online 
FROM `ViewProjet_userPoleRole` 
WHERE user_online = 1
GROUP BY pole_name
```

Hope this will help

Or you can try the following if want to display both the online and offline count:

```
SELECT pole_name, SUM(if(user_online = 1,1,0)) as nbr_online, SUM(if(user_online = 0,1,0)) as nbr_offline 
FROM `ViewProjet_userPoleRole` 
GROUP BY pole_name
```

Try this.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. Your request works but only returns the poles with the connected users. I will need to display the poles with all of the users logged out as well.

Comment: SELECT pole_name, SUM(if(user_online = 1,1,0)) as nbr_online, SUM(if(user_online = 0,1,0)) as nbr_offline 
FROM `ViewProjet_userPoleRole` 
GROUP BY pole_name

Comment: Thank you very much for your help, it also works like that.

Comment: you my code is helpful for you, then please do the favor by upvoting my answers and more.

Comment: I just did it, thanks again.